# Let $f : [0, ∞[→ [0,∞[ $ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt < ∞$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f : [0, ∞[→ [0,∞[ $ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt < ∞$. Which of the following statements are true?

a. The sequence $\{f(n)\}_{n∈\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

b. $f(n) → 0$ as $n → ∞.$

c. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent.

**My attempt:-**
Using the [Integral Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) Can we say that $a,b,c$ are true? But the answer is given that. All are false. Why can't we use integral test here?

Answer (score 3):

Integral test is applicable only when the function is monotonic.

All three are false. Draw a small triangle with base $(n-\frac 1 {n^{3}},n+\frac 1 {n^{3}})$ and height $n$  and consider a continuous function whose graph is made up of these triangles together portions of the $x-$ axis left over by these intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sure if $f$ is monotonically decreasing, so you cannot use integral test.